# Solr - sort results by maximum matches for OR search on multi-valued field

Tags: solr, lucene

Let me try to explain my problem, let's assume I have a multi-valued field called "enrolment" in each document that contains name of students in it.

Now while searching Solr, let's say I fire search for the names of three students - Manish, Amit, Navin. Now Solr returns all documents containing any one of these names (which is obviously desired in my case). Now some documents may have all 3 of them, or 2 of them or 1 of them. I want these documents/results sorted in an order such that document with maximum matching will be  at the top, followed by lesser number of matches.

I tried adding sort: score desc for this, but it doesn't work as desired because the score is "1" for all matching documents.

How can I achieve the sort order by maximum number of matches for my multi-valued field?

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: Actual one is on roll numbers, but this is how it would be in the given example -

`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/XYZ/query -d '{"query": "enrolment:Amit Manish Navin", "sort": "score desc"}'`

Comment: That really matters, since score isn't calculated for integers; if you had a tokenized textfield as you have in your question, the score calculations are different. There also isn't a `query` parameter given to Solr (the regular query is given through `q`) .. When asking a question, it's important that the question is the same as what you're trying to solve. You can probably solve your actual problem by giving boost queries for each value you're searching for instead (so `bq=field:value&bq=field:value2`).

Comment: I am doing JSON search with python code - query parameter works fine in that case. 

I am sorry I can't completely list original problem here for obvious NDA reasons. What I have described is quite close.

We need to have number search though - any way to get search ordered by relevance in terms of max matches? Not sure I understand * boost queries* that you are suggesting.

Comment: Sure, if you're using a python library, that would work, but your example uses curl directly. Please be specific in the details, as debugging something when they're not the true nature of your query it becomes hard to know what the _actual_ issue can be. [Boost queries are queries that used for increasing the score of documents](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebq_BoostQuery_Parameter), so unless I'm overseeing something, you should be able to boost the score for each matching query.

Answer (score 1):

Given a multivalued integer field where you want to rank the documents based on the number of matches, apply a boost query for each match. For example, if you have a series of monitors that come in different sizes, you can apply a boost for each size that is valid (I hacked this together and tested it with the example docs from the tech core, so that's my example and I'm sticking with it). I have two relevant documents, one named `VA902B` with `sizes` given as a multi valued field with values 23, 28, and 32, and one named `3007WFP` with values 23, 29, 36 in the same field.

Here I'm asking for any document, but give me those that have both size 28 and size 23 at the top, and then those that have either size 28 or size 23, and then any other document:

```
?bq=sizes:28&bq=sizes:23&defType=edismax&q=*:*
```

If I want to limit the set of documents to only those that match either of the sizes, I can use that as my main query:

```
?defType=edismax&q=sizes:(23%2028)
```

.. and this is where I discover that your presumption that the score is the same regardless of the number of matches is false. Adding `&debugQuery=true` to the URL gives us detailed scoring information for each document:

```
"explain": {
  "VA902B": "\n2.0 = sum of:\n  1.0 = sizes:[23 TO 23]\n  1.0 = sizes:[28 TO 28]\n",
  "3007WFP": "\n1.0 = sum of:\n  1.0 = sizes:[23 TO 23]\n"
},
```

.. which means that there is no need for applying a boost - the behaviour you want is the *standard* behaviour for Solr. This was my initial thought, but that should have given you the correct answer with the queries you gave in the comments.

But I'll show you how my strategy with applying boosts would have worked as well:

```
?bq=sizes:28&bq=sizes:23&defType=edismax&q=sizes:(23%2028)&debugQuery=true
```

.. which now tells us that the score for each document has effectively doubled, since it gets scored 1.0 (from the query) + 1.0 (from the boost) for each match.

```
"explain": {
  "VA902B": "\n4.0 = sum of:\n  2.0 = sum of:\n    1.0 = sizes:[23 TO 23]\n    1.0 = sizes:[28 TO 28]\n  1.0 = sizes:[28 TO 28]\n  1.0 = sizes:[23 TO 23]\n",
  "3007WFP": "\n2.0 = sum of:\n  1.0 = sum of:\n    1.0 = sizes:[23 TO 23]\n  1.0 = sizes:[23 TO 23]\n"
},
```

I also tested the `q=sizes(23 28)` query with the standard lucene query parser (and not dismax/edismax which support `bq`), and the behaviour was the same.

Comment: Interesting! I will recheck my results and give you my findings soon.

Comment: This is what I get when I search with `fl=score, doc_id` -->


`[{"score": 1.0, "doc_id": "2173763"}, {"score": 1.0, "doc_id": "1016369"}, {"score": 1.0, "doc_id": "1852970"}, ....]`

Comment: But the interesting part is what debugQuery shows for your documents, what the _exact_ query string sent to Solr is (you can increase logging under the admin panel to make Solr show you all queries being handled) and what the field definition for the field you are searching is.

Comment: I am sending this query to Solr - using Curl here it also returns 'incorrect' results, as in not sorted as per match percentage. 

`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/rscopyd/query -d '{"query": "enrol:5967584463319363 47822091420109848 52029559237257727 74951432392322152 90312307769130431 101846679805785709 119261714061768187 158457543043455698 165589707705448884 186553700760235568 188195153204143078 266746050454650217 282611966493106152 322861400708111322 344248443687036917 359819032150239861 364919760952004511 371334649693411795 382556016587881250 389184023380727785", "sort": "score asc"}'`

Comment: I have used `score desc`, and also with `limit` but none works. When I put numbers in parentheses (), I get no results. Note that order of these numbers is irrelevant, their existence in document is important. 

The type of "enrol" in shcema is multi-valued `plong`

Comment: This query results in `score:1` for each document matched, irrespective of how many numbers matched -->

`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/rscopyd/query?fl=doc_id,score -d '{"query": "enrol:5967584463319363 47822091420109848 52029559237257727 74951432392322152 90312307769130431 101846679805785709 119261714061768187 158457543043455698 165589707705448884 186553700760235568 188195153204143078 266746050454650217 282611966493106152 322861400708111322 344248443687036917 359819032150239861 364919760952004511 371334649693411795 382556016587881250 389184023380727785", "sort": "score asc"}`

Comment: But that's not the same query as I typed - that query will search for "5967584463319363" in the field `enrol` and the rest will be searched against the default search field (which usually is `_text_ `. You'll have to wrap the terms inside `( ... )` to make them all search against the `enrol` field. This is something `debugQuery` also will show you. So are you sure these numbers _actually_ exists in the `enrol` field - if they're not giving hits when searching against that field? What does debugQuery say in that case? What is the type of the field?

Comment: The plong type (LongPointField) matches what I have in my example.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MatsLindh, the default search field is same - `enrol`. The debugQuery indeed shows what you're saying. `_text_` field search, though schema has it as `MV-plong` (`plongs`, to be accurate). 

However, as I mentioned earlier when I put all these numbers in parentheses `()` I get 0 docs. The docs may contain 0 to n numbers that is a subset of my query (list of numbers I am sending) - I want list of documents sorted based on highest matches first. 

How do I do this?

Comment: What you want is the default behaviour - since you're not getting any matches when you're wrapping the values within `field:( ... )`, this seems to indicate that the `field` doesn't have the values you think it does, or that your default search operator is `AND`. Try with a single value (i.e. `enrol:5967584463319363`) and see if you get a hit. If not, your field isn't suitable for searching at all, either because of it not being indexed, or it being changed after the content was indexed.

Comment: I also thought/believed that it was the default behaviour, but that's not how I see it in my results. The default search operator is `OR` - I have already checked that.

Let me index all the data from scratch again and use fresh schema to see what I get. Because, this indeed should be the *default* behaviour.

Comment: And you have confirmed that the field is actually being indexed? (i.e. index="true")?

Comment: Yes, it is being indexed.